# hadoop container killed but job succeed

Tags: hadoop, containers, virtual-memory

I'm trying to execute a map reduce program on hadoop.
When I submitted the jar on my Macbook and run the job at a desktop, a job failed with  container beyond virtual memory limits. But the 
http://master-hadoop:8088/cluster told me that my job succeed with the result seem to be correct.

You can see that the physical memory used is of size 170MB while the virtual memory used is of size 17.8GB. And the file inputed is of only 10MB.

What I can't figure out is that why the program is using so much virtual memory and why hadoop said that my job succeed and so it is the result possibly since the container had been killed.

```
16/11/07 21:31:40 INFO Join: 20161107213140620
16/11/07 21:31:41 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/07 21:31:42 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master-hadoop/192.168.199.162:8032
16/11/07 21:31:43 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/11/07 21:31:44 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
16/11/07 21:31:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/11/07 21:31:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1478524274348_0001
16/11/07 21:31:46 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1478524274348_0001
16/11/07 21:31:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master-hadoop:8088/proxy/application_1478524274348_0001/
16/11/07 21:31:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1478524274348_0001
16/11/07 21:31:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1478524274348_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/11/07 21:31:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/11/07 21:32:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/11/07 21:32:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/11/07 21:32:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1478524274348_0001 completed successfully
16/11/07 21:32:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=1974092
        FILE: Number of bytes written=4301313
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=20971727
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=23746
        HDFS: Number of read operations=9
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=2
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=13291
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=3985
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=13291
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=3985
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=13291
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=3985
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=13609984
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=4080640
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=162852
        Map output records=162852
        Map output bytes=1648382
        Map output materialized bytes=1974098
        Input split bytes=207
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=105348
        Reduce shuffle bytes=1974098
        Reduce input records=162852
        Reduce output records=4423
        Spilled Records=325704
        Shuffled Maps =2
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=2
        GC time elapsed (ms)=364
        CPU time spent (ms)=6300
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=705949696
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=5738041344
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=492830720
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=20971520
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=23746
16/11/07 21:32:12 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master-hadoop/192.168.199.162:8032
16/11/07 21:32:12 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/11/07 21:32:12 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
16/11/07 21:32:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/11/07 21:32:13 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1478524274348_0002
16/11/07 21:32:13 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1478524274348_0002
16/11/07 21:32:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master-hadoop:8088/proxy/application_1478524274348_0002/
16/11/07 21:32:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1478524274348_0002
16/11/07 21:32:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1478524274348_0002 running in uber mode : false
16/11/07 21:32:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/11/07 21:32:32 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/11/07 21:32:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1478524274348_0002_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Container [pid=4170,containerID=container_1478524274348_0002_01_000004] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 170.0 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 17.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1478524274348_0002_01_000004 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 4174 4170 4170 4170 (java) 407 30 19121176576 42828 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx200m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/lining/appcache/application_1478524274348_0002/container_1478524274348_0002_01_000004/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1478524274348_0002/container_1478524274348_0002_01_000004 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logger=INFO,shuffleCLA -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logfile=syslog.shuffle -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.log.filesize=0 -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.log.backups=0 org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.1.1 33077 attempt_1478524274348_0002_r_000000_0 4 
    |- 4170 4168 4170 4170 (bash) 0 0 17051648 700 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Xmx200m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/lining/appcache/application_1478524274348_0002/container_1478524274348_0002_01_000004/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1478524274348_0002/container_1478524274348_0002_01_000004 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logger=INFO,shuffleCLA -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logfile=syslog.shuffle -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.log.filesize=0 -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.log.backups=0 org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.1.1 33077 attempt_1478524274348_0002_r_000000_0 4 1>/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1478524274348_0002/container_1478524274348_0002_01_000004/stdout 2>/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1478524274348_0002/container_1478524274348_0002_01_000004/stderr  

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

16/11/07 21:32:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/11/07 21:32:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1478524274348_0002 completed successfully
16/11/07 21:32:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 50
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=3373558
        FILE: Number of bytes written=7100224
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=21019219
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=307797
        HDFS: Number of read operations=15
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
        Failed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=2
        Launched reduce tasks=2
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=12513
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=7584
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=12513
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=7584
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=12513
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=7584
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=12813312
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=7766016
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=162852
        Map output records=22115
        Map output bytes=3315932
        Map output materialized bytes=3373564
        Input split bytes=207
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=177
        Reduce shuffle bytes=3373564
        Reduce input records=22115
        Reduce output records=17692
        Spilled Records=44230
        Shuffled Maps =2
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=2
        GC time elapsed (ms)=381
        CPU time spent (ms)=5320
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=727543808
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=22958596096
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=493355008
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=20971520
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=307797
16/11/07 21:32:48 INFO Join: 20161107213248192
```

Comment: I never set anything in the config relating vmem and pmem

Answer (score 1):

The first attempt of one of your reduce task failed but was most likely rescheduled and then completed successfully which is why your entire job reports success.